# Optimize Google Maps API Polygone like Route Planner

Tags: google-maps, routes

I have a big backyard and I was wondering if there was a way to use google maps api polygon shape and route planner to plan the best path to mow.  Is there a shape path optimizer not just for streets?

Answer (score 0):

I did few things with google maps api and there is not such thing as optimize functions for shapes. What you can do is use google maps points and implement something like Graham  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan to finde shapes but to optimize it you will have to implement your own algorithm.

Google Maps v3 reference is here: (maybe i missed something) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference